# Help me find my mistake for this variance

Tags: statistics, variance

Suppose X is an observation from a distribution with probability mass function 
$$X\sim f(x)=\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)^{\left | x \right |}(1-\theta)^{1-\left | x \right |} 1_{A}(x)$$ $$0<\theta<1$$ where $$A=\left \{ 1,0,-1 \right.\left.  \right \}$$ 
Suppose $$T(X)=2 \cdot 1_{B}(x)$$ where $$B=\left \{ 1 \right.\left.  \right \}$$
I am trying to find the variance of T and this is what i did :
 $$V(T)=E(4 \cdot 1_{B} ^2) - E^2(2 \cdot  1_{B})$$ where i used the fact that $$V(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)$$
We can show that $$E(T)=\theta$$ 
So the variance can now be written as 
$$V(T)=4[1^2 f(1,\theta) + 0^2  f(0,\theta)] - (\theta)^2$$
Can you spot my mistake?

Comment: Is it the missing $0^2f(-1,\theta)$ term in your last displayed equation?

Comment: I missed that value by mistake,apart from that i still don't get the desired result which makes me think that the textbook has the wrong answer?To calculate E(T)=2*f(1,θ)+0*f(0,θ)+0*f(-1,θ),is that correct?

Comment: I think it's alright. Why do you think it is wrong? What does the book have?

Comment: @ArnabAuddy It's not exactly a textbook,it is from a sheet of exercises and it contains the final answer but not the calculations.Apart from the 0^2 * f(-1,θ) missing term,you don't see any other mistake?Thanks for helping,i appreciate it.